# Creating a form with user input letter grade

Tags: php, forms, get

So I need to create a simple form where the user inputs a letter great in the text box, grades from A, B, C, D, or F and then gets a display saying a certain sentence.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Letter Grades</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LetterGrades.php" method="get" >
        <p>Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" />
        <input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course using the `$_GET` method. Can anyone help out? Stuck at work with 1 other worker so I'm short staff.

Comment: *"and then gets a display saying a certain sentence."* - being what exactly? question's very unclear

Comment: if A is input in the form then you'll get a "Your grade is excellent", messages like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Make an array containing sentences with the index being the grade.

```
$grade_sentences = array(
    'A' => 'Great Job!',
    'B' => 'Good Job!',
    'C' => 'Not bad!',
    'D' => 'Could use a little work',
    'F' => 'I\'ve seen worse'
);
```

Then check if the array key exists and return the associated sentence.

```
if(array_key_exists($_GET['grade'], $grade_sentences)){
    echo $grade_sentences[$_GET['grade']];
}
```